# How can I set the actual store in a cms block

Tags: multistore, store-view

I have in my phtml file the follow code:

```
$store = Mage::app()->setStore($storeId);
/*$store = Mage::app()->getStore();*/
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$code  = $store->getCode();
$enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/config6/active',$code);
```

And like to show the latest products we imported in this store view (multistore).

But it not shows from this specific cms page. This is my block I use:

```
{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" product_count="20" products_column="6" template="smartwave/filterproducts/home_latest.phtml"}}
```

And here is my phtml:

```
<?php
$store = Mage::app()->setStore($storeId);
/*$store = Mage::app()->getStore();*/
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$code  = $store->getCode();
$enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/config6/active',$code);
?>
<?php if($enable == 1 && $this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="slider-latest-container">
    <div class="more-title">
        <h2 class="title"><span><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/config6/title',$code); ?></span></h2>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('filterproducts/index/latest'); ?>" class="show-more-link"><?php echo $this->__('View More Products') ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="products-slider items-slider latest-slider column<?php echo $this->get_product_column(); ?>">
        <ul class="products-grid">
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="item-area">
                        <div class="product-image-wrapper <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/effect_img', $code)): ?>hover-effect-slider"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php 
                            // Get the Special Price
                            $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
                            // Get the Special Price FROM date
                            $specialPriceFromDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getSpecialFromDate();
                            // Get the Special Price TO date
                            $specialPriceToDate = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getSpecialToDate();
                            // Get Current date
                            $today =  time();

                            if ($specialprice){
                                if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)){
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig("legenda_setting/product_label/sale", $code)){
                        ?>
                                    <span class="label-icon sale-label">Sale!</span>
                        <?php       
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php
                            $now = date("Y-m-d");
                            $newsFrom= substr($_item->getData('news_from_date'),0,10);
                            $newsTo=  substr($_item->getData('news_to_date'),0,10);
                            if ($newsTo != '' || $newsFrom != ''){
                                if (($newsTo != '' && $newsFrom != '' && $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo) || ($newsTo == '' && $now >=$newsFrom) || ($newsFrom == '' && $now<=$newsTo))
                                {
                                    if(Mage::getStoreConfig("legenda_setting/product_label/new", $code)){
                            ?> 
                                    <span class="label-icon new-label second-label">New!</span>
                            <?php 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php 
                            $imgList = ''; 
                            if (Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/effect_img', $code)) {
                                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId());
                                foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                                    // If no image, skip 
                                    if ($image->getFile() == NULL)
                                        continue;
                                    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/aspect_ratio', $code)) {
        //                                $imgList .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile()).',';
                                        $imgList .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item,'thumbnail',$image->getFile())->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350).',';   
                                    } else {
                                        $imgWidth = Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/ratio_width', $code);
                                        $imgHeight = Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/ratio_height', $code);
                                        $imgList .= Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_item,'thumbnail',$image->getFile())->resize($imgWidth, $imgHeight).',';
                                    }
                                }
                                $imgList = substr($imgList, 0, strlen($imgList) - 1);
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?php if(!$_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_item, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image" data-images-list="<?php echo $imgList; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/aspect_ratio', $code)):?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(FALSE)->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(350); ?><?php else: ?><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/ratio_width', $code), Mage::getStoreConfig('legenda_setting/category/ratio_height', $code)); ?><?php endif; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_item, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                        </a>
                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('quickview/general/enableview', $code)): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="sw-product-quickview"><?php echo $this->__('Quick View') ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="description-wrapper">
                            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h3>
                            <?php if($_item->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                            <div class="actions">
                            <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory')): ?>
                                <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php  if ( !($_item->getData('has_options') || $_item->isGrouped()) ) :  ?>
                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" onclick="setLocationAjax('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>','<?php echo $_item->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Select Option') ?>" class="button btn-cart btn-cart-<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" onclick="showOptions('<?php echo $_item->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Select Option') ?></span></span></button>
                                        <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxcart/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_item->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_item->getId()?>' style='display:none'>Options</a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" class="button"><?php echo $this->__('Read More') ?></a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('ajaxcart/addtolinks/enablecategory')): ?>
                                <ul class="add-to-links">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <li><a href="#" onclick='ajaxWishlist("<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_item) ?>","<?php echo $_item->getId()?>");return false;' class="link-wishlist link-wishlist-<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_item)): ?>
                                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="#" onclick='ajaxCompare("<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>","<?php echo $_item->getId()?>");return false;' class="link-compare link-compare-<?php echo $_item->getId()?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>                        
                                </ul>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <ul class="add-to-links">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist button"></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_item)): ?>
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare button"></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery('.latest-slider .products-grid').owlCarousel({
        items: <?php echo $this->get_product_column() ?>,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [991, 3],
        itemsTablet: [768, 2],
        itemsMobile: [479, 1],
        lazyLoad: true,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: true
    });
//]]>
</script>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="content-element">
    <div class="note-msg"><span class="msg-content"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></span></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do with store id. But if you have your store id you can filter product collection by store id this way.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

You can set this product collection in block file and use that in template. This way you can speed up the page load time. In your case, I see you are loading same product multiple times in loop and this will not a good idea.

Comment: I like to have a carousel with the newest products. The code above was given from the template. But it shows all the time only the same products.

And I do not know how the "split" it up, so I like to get in 4 different store views (multistore), 4 different amount of products.

If you know how to do it... maybe You can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am trying to indicate the problem in your code. However your actaul question is different I know.

```
$store = Mage::app()->setStore($storeId);
$code  = $store->getCode();
```

This is because `Mage::app()` returns an isntance of `Mage_Core_Model_App`. This class does not hold the method `setStore()` and the class is not inheriting from any other classes. You can use either of two options below

**1. Using getStoreConfig()**

```
$storeId = 3; //put your store id here.
$store   = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
$code    = $store->getCode();
$enable  = (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('filterproducts/config6/active',$code);
```

**2. Using getStoreConfigFlag()**

```
$storeId = 3; //put your store id here.
$store   = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
$code    = $store->getCode();
$enable  = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('filterproducts/config6/active',$code);
```

We are grabbing desired store using `getStore()` method itself. See [**`Mage_Core_Model_App:getStore()`**](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php#L827) method for reference. Another difference is you can use [**`getStoreConfigFlag()`**](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/Mage.php#L363) method in *`app\Mage.php`* to get boolean values. You can either use it or go on with the first approach I have shown.

### EDIT

I can see you are using `getItems()` method to grab your collection. If that method returns same collection for every store, then you need to put store filtering inside that method.

So open your block class `[Namespace]_Filterproducts_Latest_Home_List` and edit your `getItems()` method and put store filetering there. For an example

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->setStore($store);
```

Comment: Hi
I tried both "versions". It just not do any single change. All the time only the same products.
I do not know what I do wrong.

Comment: @SimonVetterli First part of my answer indicates the issues in your code. Your question is not clearly talk about your real problem. The real answer to your question resides in the edit part.

Comment: Hi
I can't follow You, where and in what file I need to edit something. I am new in Magento, only try to find a solution for my problem. But how to realize, I have no idea.

Comment: @SimonVetterli `filterproducts/latest_home_list` this block type value indicates to a class. you need to find that class and make edit there. I can't help you further on this. Because you need understanding of Magento blocks and layouts in order to understand what I am saying. With the given  details, this is the maximum that I can point out. Rest is your job